# Изменение ширины колонок таблицы

Tags: html, вёрстка

Подскажи-те пожалуйста, возможно ли сверстать таблицу, чтобы у пользователя была возможность самому изменять ширину колонок?

Comment: Конечно, можно! Только сейчас то, кто меняет эту ширину? Обама?

Comment: Без javascript ?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit: что Вас смущает? Просто неизвестно какие цели у ТС. Но одним HTML точно не обойтись :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В виду отсутствия дополнительной информации и каких-либо условий со стороны автора вопроса, предложу простой вариант на CSS с использованием вложенных параграфов со свойством `resize`:

```css
table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0px red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

td { box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0px red; }

td p {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-width: 1.5em;
}
tr:first-of-type td p {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><p>1</p></td><td><p>2</p></td><td><p>3</p></td><td><p>4</p></td></tr>
  <tr><td><p>5</p></td><td><p>6</p></td><td><p>7</p></td><td><p>8</p></td></tr>
  <tr><td><p>9</p></td><td><p>10</p></td><td><p>11</p></td><td><p>12</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

В Chrome можно задавать `resize` непосредственно ячейкам таблицы, но к сожалению другие браузеры категорически против:

```css
table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0px red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0px red;
}
tr:first-of-type td {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```

Также в Chrome, если задавать `resize` для ячеек, можно задать изменение не только ширины или высоты, но и в обоих направлениях одновременно (правда, логика работы становится не совсем понятна, а поведение оставляет желать лучшего):

```css
table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 0px red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0px red;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```